# Mysql UPDATE JOIN with LOAD DATA INFILE from csv

Tags: mysql, csv, join, sql-update

Here are my tables :

```
table1
id_town  town_altitude_min  town_altitude_max
1        NULL               NULL
2        NULL               NULL
...

table2
id_town  id_zipcode
1        1100
2        1100
3        1110
...
```

And my csv :

```
id_zipcode;town_altitude_min;town_altitude_max
1100;20;350
1110;243;440
...
```

How can I update the table1 town_altitude_min and town_altitude_max with the data in the csv file ?

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Query and you can find **/tmp** directory inside **result.csv**

```
SELECT table2.id_zipcode, table1.town_altitude_min, table1.town_altitude_max INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id_town = table1.id_town
```

I hope it will Helps.